# Jenkinsfile - add a FilterPolicy to AWS SNS Subcription

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-sns

I'd like to know what's the right way to do it. This is my JenkinsFile:

```
# more code...

aws sns subscribe \
    --topic-arn $SNS_ARN \
    --protocol lambda \
    --attributes FilterPolicy='{\"countries\":[\"Sweden\"]}' \
    --notification-endpoint $NOTIFICATION_ENDPOINT\
    --region $REGION

# more code...
```

If I run this in AWS CLI it subscribes correctly and adds the FilterPolicy, but doesn't add the FilterPolicy if run in Jenkins.

Comment: Most probably the `AWS CLI` version you are using on `Jenkins` server is not up-to-date. Can you check what version of `AWS CLI` you are using on `Jenkins` server vs where it works?

Comment: I'm using the latest version (1.16.78). I suspect it's something related to character escaping, but I've tried every combination that came to my mind

Comment: aren't you supposed to have \ at the end of `    --attributes FilterPolicy='{\"countries\":[\"Sweden\"]}` for line continuation?

Comment: I mispelled it in this question, but actually included in JenkinsFile